# How to use git submodules properly in cmake project?

Tags: git, cmake, git-submodules

I have a `Cmake` project that should be a library for another project and should be run as a standalone application. Both projects use the same external library as a git submodule. What is the correct way to do it? Here is my structure:

```
ProjectParent/
  lib/
    /externalLib
    /ProjectChild
      /lib
        /externalLib
```

I can not remove externalLib from ProjectChild because it should run as a standalone application, it is not just a library. I don't want to remove externalLib from ProjectParent too. Do we have any option in cmake like exclude option in gradle?

Also I just add "include("lib/ProjectChild")" to cmake file. Is it right?

Comment: You should not have `externalLib` twice. If ProjectChild already uses externalLib, then ProjectParent can use it

Comment: You should be including `lib/ProjectChild/lib/externalLib` to supply `externalLib` in the parent.

Comment: Yes but maybe they doesn't like ProjectChild and want to remove that feature in future so I just want to turn off one of them right now.

Comment: https://github.com/psi4/psi4/wiki/External-subprojects-using-Git-and-CMake